# Encode sequences of integers for randomness testing

Tags: encryption, random, binary, prng

I need to test the randomness of multiple sequences of integers. All sequences have the same number of integers, all integers are of range [0, 55439] (including 0 and 55439). I'm planning to test them with the NIST test suite (http://csrc.nist.gov/rng).

The NIST test suite only accept binary streams, so I must encode those integers into binary strings of the same length. Since 55440 isn't a power of 2, I cannot use the binary representation of these integers. If the binary representation is used, the most significant bit of the the representation is more likely to be 0, which will result in false negatives.

How should those integers be encoded ?

Comment: Either use a different RNG test suite, such as [DieHarder](http://www.phy.duke.edu/~rgb/General/dieharder.php), or rejig your generator to produce numbers in [0, 65535] or [0, 32767], whichever is easier.  If the underlying RNG is correct, then either, or both will pass the tests.

Comment: Ask at [crypto](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: It stands to reason that the process by which a binary RNG can be used to produce non-binary ranges can be adapted to perform the inverse operation; however, my suspicion is that even the very weakest PRNG would pass most randomness tests if you ran it forward and backward through those processes, and all you would demonstrate is that the tests were unfit for this task.  Perhaps your best hope is [TestU01](http://simul.iro.umontreal.ca/testu01/tu01.html), but that'll leave you a lot of work to finish for yourself.